# How to zip and clean up downloaded files after crawling with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have successfully created a crawler with scrapy which downloads to CSV and pulls images into images/full folder.

Now I want to clean it up after the crawl by pulling the files into a zip archive and removing the "full" folder and the CSV as well.

This is how I do it:

parser_attributes.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# interpret attributes
def gender(i):
    switcher={
            'damen & herren' : 1,
            'herren, unisex' : 1,
            'unisex' : 1,
            'damen' : 2,
            'herren' : 6
         }
    for k, v in switcher.items():
        if k.lower() in i.lower():
            return v
    return "Invalid: " + i
```

test.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
import logging
# from urllib.parse import urlparse
import os
import zipfile
import shutil # zip archive generator
import datetime

# images
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline

from bid.items import myitem

# import translater for attributes
# would rather use import parser_attributes but could not get this working with e.g. import parser_attributes or import bid.parser_attributes
exec(open("/Volumes/zero/Users/user/test_crawl/bid/bid/spiders/parser_attributes.py").read())


class GetbidSpider(CrawlSpider):
    # create a spider
    # some more code here ...
    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(allow=['rule']), 
            callback='parse_item'
        ),
    )
    def parse_item(self, response):

        ### do something

        return myitem

def cleanup(name):
    # create zip archive with all images inside
    filename = '/Users/user/test_crawl/bid/zip/test_' +  datetime.datetime.now().strftime ("%Y%m%d-%H%m%S")
    imagefolder = '/Users/user/test_crawl/bid/images/full'
    shutil.make_archive(filename, 'zip', imagefolder) 
    # delete images
    shutil.rmtree(imagefolder)

    # add csv file to  zip archive
    filename_zip = filename + '.zip'
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(filename_zip,'a') 
    path_to_file = '/Users/user/test_crawl/bid/csv/181201_test.csv'
    zip.write(path_to_file, os.path.basename(path_to_file)) # add file under same directory without folder names
    zip.close()

cleanup('name')
```

Traceback:

```
 scrapy crawl test -o csv/181201_test.csv -t csv 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 149, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 249, in __init__
    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 137, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 336, in _get_spider_loader
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 61, in from_settings
    return cls(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._load_all_spiders()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 47, in _load_all_spiders
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/user/test_crawl/bid/bid/spiders/test.py", line 96, in <module>
    cleanup('test')
  File "/Users/user/test_crawl/bid/bid/spiders/test.py", line 84, in cleanup
    shutil.make_archive(filename, 'zip', imagefolder) 
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 792, in make_archive
    os.chdir(root_dir)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/user/test_crawl/bid/images/full'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main ways of executing a scrapy spider:

- [Using the command line tool](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html)
- [Using the API](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script)

Your code tries to mix the two ways, which is not going to work.

There are two ways I can think of to do what you want:

- Create a [custom pipeline](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#writing-your-own-item-pipeline) and handle your zipping/deleting logic in its `close_spider` method
- Create a custom [storage](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#supported-storage) and [exporter](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html) which would store the information in a zip file to begin with

The former is probably simpler, but the latter avoids the need for zipping and deleting your files after the scraping process completes.

```
# import translater for attributes
# would rather use import parser_attributes but could not get this working with e.g. import parser_attributes or import bid.parser_attributes
exec(open("/Volumes/zero/Users/user/test_crawl/bid/bid/spiders/parser_attributes.py").read())
```

You just need to use the correct absolute import path.
This would probably achieve the same, but in a much less horrible way:

```
from bid.spiders.parser_attributes import gender
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this within pipelines.py: class BidPipeline(object):
        def process_item(self, item, spider):
            return item
        def close_spider(self, spider)
            cleanup('test'), but it never executes after the spider finishes. Also regarding the import, would I need to add a line for every of the 100 attributes in the same way as "gender", like color, form, etc.?

Comment: Did you activate the pipeline in your `settings.py`? Also, something like `from bid.spiders import parser_attributes` and then using `parser_attributes.gender` etc. might make more sense.

Comment: Getting closer. Now at least an error shows up:   File "/Users/user/test_crawl/bid/bid/pipelines.py", line 13, in close_spider
    cleanup('rieger') NameError: name 'cleanup' is not defined. Where would I need to define the method?

Comment: In the file you're using it in. Or at least you'll need to import it there.

Comment: It apears that the json file within the zip archive is truncated due to zipping it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53602641/json-file-gets-damaged-while-putting-it-into-a-zip-archive-with-python Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: I had a look at the implementation of feed exports, and it turns out the files are closed when processing the `spider_closed` signal as well, which means the file might not be closed yet when your `close_spider()` method is called. I guess your best option is creating a custom exporter and/or storage after all

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it with your help and answered the other question accordingly.