# json file get's damaged while putting it into a zip archive with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

After crawling a site with scrapy, I am creating a zip archive within the closing method, pulling pictures into it.
Then I add a valid json file to the archive.

After unzipping (on mac os x or ubuntu) the json file will show up damaged. The last item is missing.

End of decompressed file:

```
..a46.jpg"]},
```

Original file:

```
a46.jpg"]}]
```

Code:

```
# create zip archive with all images inside
filename = '../zip/' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime ("%Y%m%d-%H%M") + '_' + name
imagefolder = 'full'
imagepath = '/Users/user/test_crawl/bid/images'
shutil.make_archive(
    filename, 
    'zip', 
    imagepath,
    imagefolder
) 

# add json file to zip archive
filename_zip = filename + '.zip'
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(filename_zip,'a') 
path_to_file = '/Users/user/test_crawl/bid/data/'+  
datetime.datetime.now().strftime ("%Y%m%d") + '_' + name + '.json'
zip.write(path_to_file, os.path.basename(path_to_file)) 
zip.close()
```

I could reproduce this error several times and everything else looks OK.

Comment: did you `.flush()` the json file before putting it to the archive?

Comment: no, would this help? I got an error trying to flush it (path_to_file.flush() ) : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'flush'

Comment: `path_to_file` is a path, not a file object. Possible explanation to the incomplete file is that the process/thread writing this file does not close it. In this case, it will miss file ending because it is cached in RAM but isn't written to disk. If this is the case, it could be solved by calling `.flush()` on the file object from that process/thread.

Comment: nope, this isn't the case. If it was just no flushing, you wouldn't get the trailing comma. Still, the problem is in the process/thread writing the JSON file.

Comment: I guess you are right, the zipping is handled within the close_spider method of scrapy: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#writing-your-own-item-pipeline However it should be done by the time since it is called from there when the spider finishes. At least this is my current understandig from it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use scrapy jsonitemexporter instead of fead exporter as the feed exporter will write to the file during close_spider(), which is to late.

This is done pretty easy.

load JsonItemExporter inside file pipelines.py

```
from scrapy.exporters import JsonItemExporter
```

Change your pipeline like this:

```
class MyPipeline(object):

    file = None

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.file = open('data/test.json', 'wb')
        self.exporter = JsonItemExporter(self.file)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        self.file.close()
        cleanup('zip_method')

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

The zip_method contains the zip code mentioned in the question.